# Centering only the columns selected, leaving other columns intact

Tags: r, dplyr

Example data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), x1 = c(2.6, 3.8, 2.6, 4.3, 
2.6), x2 = c(3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 4, 3.2), x3 = c(4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3, 
4.5), x4 = c(2.4, 3, 2.4, 3.1, 2.4), x5 = c(3.8, 2.6, 4.3, 2.6, 
4.4), x6 = c(3.2, 3.2, 4, 3.2, 2.2), x7 = c(3.5, 4.5, 3, 4.5, 
4), x8 = c(3, 2.4, 3.1, 2.4, 4.3), x9 = c(3.9, 4, 4, 4, 3.9), 
    x10 = c(4, 3.9, 4, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), variable.labels = structure(character(0), .Names = character(0)), codepage = 65001L)
```

I'm trying to mean-center only columns 6:10. I would like to ask for your advice on changing the code below that would keep all the 11 columns of the original data, and append the newly centered columns (so in total 16 columns). Currently, the code below only allows for centering the selected columns:

```
center.scale <- function(c) {
  x <- scale(c, center = T, scale = F)
  colnames(x) <- paste0(colnames(x), "_c")
  cbind(c, x)
}

centered_data <- center.scale(original_data[,c(6:10)])
```

p.s.

I have tried the code below, but strangely, it keeps on producing centering results that are not accurate.

```
data2 <- original_data %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = colnames(original_data[6:10]),
            .funs = list("c" = center_scale))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may pass an index into the function and do the subset inside

```
center.scale <- function(dat, ind) {

  x <- scale(dat[, ind], center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
  colnames(x) <- paste0(colnames(x), "_c")
  cbind(dat, x)
}
```

-testing

```
> center.scale(original_data, 5:10)
  ID  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9 x10  x4_c  x5_c  x6_c x7_c  x8_c  x9_c
1  1 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 3.8 3.2 3.5 3.0 3.9 4.0 -0.26  0.26  0.04 -0.4 -0.04 -0.06
2  2 3.8 3.2 3.5 3.0 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 4.0 3.9  0.34 -0.94  0.04  0.6 -0.64  0.04
3  3 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 4.3 4.0 3.0 3.1 4.0 4.0 -0.26  0.76  0.84 -0.9  0.06  0.04
4  4 4.3 4.0 3.0 3.1 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 4.0 4.0  0.44 -0.94  0.04  0.6 -0.64  0.04
5  5 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 4.4 2.2 4.0 4.3 3.9 4.0 -0.26  0.86 -0.96  0.1  1.26 -0.06
```

Comment: I'm working on large data, and I keep on getting errors of 'New names:
* NA -> ...131' (where the centered variables are supposed to start from column #131). When I run on sample data, it works fine; do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @user14250906 do you have a `data.table` as input in your original data.  The code works with `tibble` or `data.frame` though

Comment: @user14250906 if it is a data.table, then you may need `with = FALSE` while indexing.  Without that info, it is not clear to me

Comment: Thank you, it is data.frame; I will try again by subsetting the columns.

Comment: @user14250906 i tried with all NA columns, even that works.  But, it will fail when the column is not numeric i.e character.  I assumed these are numeric columns

Comment: I have been grappling with this for a few days...and it seems like this has to do with dplyr's ungroup() function. I have added ungroup() and it seems like working! Need to check with other datasets if this is really true....

Comment: @user14250906 that would be an issue because `group_by` creates an attributes that prevents.  Generally, I would use `ungroup` after the `mutate` as this can be create bugs like this

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(across(x6:x10, scale, scale = FALSE, .names = '{.col}_c'))

  ID  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9 x10  x6_c x7_c  x8_c  x9_c x10_c
1  1 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 3.8 3.2 3.5 3.0 3.9 4.0  0.04 -0.4 -0.04 -0.06  0.02
2  2 3.8 3.2 3.5 3.0 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 4.0 3.9  0.04  0.6 -0.64  0.04 -0.08
3  3 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 4.3 4.0 3.0 3.1 4.0 4.0  0.84 -0.9  0.06  0.04  0.02
4  4 4.3 4.0 3.0 3.1 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 4.0 4.0  0.04  0.6 -0.64  0.04  0.02
5  5 2.6 3.2 4.5 2.4 4.4 2.2 4.0 4.3 3.9 4.0 -0.96  0.1  1.26 -0.06  0.02
```